# Crear tabla con cabecera fija y generar un scroll vertical

Tags: css, html5

Estoy trabajando en una tabla desde HTML y CSS, lo que necesito es generar una tabla la cual el contenido dentro de las etiquetas **thead** quede estático la cual obviamente es la cabecera de una tabla, y el contenido dentro de **tbody** se genere un scroll vertical. Y tengo el [siguiente codigo](https://jsfiddle.net/josemn/0L97r9x0/) pero no he podido generar esa funcionalidad, si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Codigo HTML:

```
<div class="scroll-div-tablas" id="TablaContenedor" style="height: 315px;">
   <table class="ListaTabla" id="Topicos_Datatable">
       <thead id="Topicos_Cabecera_Datos">
           <tr>
               <th style="width: 5%;"></th>
               <th id="th" style="width: 10%;">Clave</th>
               <th id="th" style="width: 15%;">Tópico</th>
               <th id="th" style="width: 20%;">Descripción</th>
               <th id="th" style="width: 20%;">Objetivo</th>
               <th id="th" style="width: 20%;">Justificación</th>
               <th id="th" style="width: 20%;">Área de estudio</th>
           </tr>
           </thead>
               <tbody id="gtnp_Listado_Datos">
                  <tr>
                    <td><input name="topic" id="radiobtn28" type="radio" value="28"></td>
                    <td title="002" id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(28)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">002</p></td>
                    <td title="Soporte Técnico." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(28)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Soporte Técnico.</p></td>
                    <td title="Evaluaciones correspondiente a soporte Tecnico." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(28)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Evaluaciones correspondiente a soporte Tecnico.</p></td>
                    <td title="Las evaluaciones que son parte de este tópico son relacionadas a soporte técnico." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(28)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Las evaluaciones que son parte de este tópico son relacionadas a soporte técnico.</p></td>
                    <td title="Conocer el grado de conocimiento." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(28)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Conocer el grado de conocimiento.</p></td>
                    <td title="Soporte Técnico." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(28)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Soporte Técnico.</p></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input name="topic" id="radiobtn29" type="radio" value="29"></td>
                    <td title="003" id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(29)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">003</p></td>
                    <td title="Desarrollo." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(29)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Desarrollo.</p></td>
                    <td title="Evaluaciones&nbsp;de aplicaciones para desarrollo." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(29)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Evaluaciones&nbsp;de aplicaciones para desarrollo.</p></td>
                    <td title="Evaluar los conocimientos de los usuarios encuestados referente a las distintas aplicaciones de desarrollo." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(29)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Evaluar los conocimientos de los usuarios encuestados referente a las distintas aplicaciones de desarrollo.</p></td>
                    <td title="Mediantes las encuestas relacionadas a este tópico se evaluaran a los usuarios para medir el grado de conocimiento sobre una aplicación especifica." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(29)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Mediantes las encuestas relacionadas a este tópico se evaluaran a los usuarios para medir el grado de conocimiento sobre una aplicación especifica.</p></td>
                    <td title="Desarrollo." id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(29)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Desarrollo.</p></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input name="topic" id="radiobtn42" type="radio" value="42"></td>
                    <td title="004" id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(42)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">004</p></td>
                    <td title="Topicos PMBOK" id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(42)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Topicos PMBOK</p></td>
                    <td title="Topicos PMBOK" id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(42)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Topicos PMBOK</p></td>
                    <td title="Topicos PMBOK" id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(42)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Topicos PMBOK</p></td>
                    <td title="Topicos PMBOK" id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(42)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Topicos PMBOK</p></td>
                    <td title="Topicos PMBOK" id="td" onclick="TopicosModule.elementoSeleccionado(42)"><p style="margin: 0px auto; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 11px;">Topicos PMBOK</p></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Código CSS:

```
#Topicos_Datatable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

table.ListaTabla {
    width: 100%;
    color: #666;
    border: none;
    font-family: "century gothic", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div .ListaTabla {
    border: 2px solid lightgray !important;
}

.ListaTabla th {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    color: #727374;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #D1D0C6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

#Topicos_Datatable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

table.ListaTabla td {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 8pt;
    border: 2px solid #D1D0C6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead, tbody { display: block; }
tbody {
    height: 315px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
thead {
    height: 37px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

He actualizado un poco el código

Comment: Hola José, por favor coloca el código en tu publicación; de igual forma se puede poner código ejecutable. Si el enlace en cuestión cae, no se podría reproducir tu problema debido a que no habrá código.

Comment: Hola Gustavo gracias lo tomaré en cuenta

Comment: Si lo tomas en cuenta para esta pregunta sería genial..

Answer (score 2):

Simplifica. Tienes mucho código que no hace nada. Empieza por este `css`, sólo escribe este código, y luego ves añadiendo lo que necesites para que se adapte a tu diseño. He añadido una nueva clase (`header_fijo`) a la tabla respetando tus `id's` y a mi me funciona:

```
<table class="ListaTabla header_fijo" id="Topicos_Datatable">
```

Y el css:

```
.header_fijo {
  width: 750px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.header_fijo thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FDFDFD;
}
.header_fijo thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.header_fijo tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Hola Javi, gracias por tu respuesta, estoy tratando de implementarla

Comment: No me funciona, estoy usando un `datatable` dentro de un `modal`, no se si eso tenga algo que ver :(

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilice exactamente este desarrollo de GitHub , viene documentado y explicado

Te deja congelar filas en la cabecera y a la izquierda para que funcione como si fuera excel , obvio con un origen de datos dinamicos , sql , notepad, texto plano etc etc , sirve con javascript y html y el codigo es muy limpio y te permite editar el css

https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll

Basta con agregar el archivo en forma de script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/gridviewScroll.min.js">        </script>
```

Llamas la función y modificas los parámetros , ancho , cuantas filas se van a congelar  , etc etc  esto ultimo esta en la documentación

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            gridviewScroll();
        });

        function gridviewScroll() {
            gridView1 = $('#GridView11').gridviewScroll({                               
                width: "100%",
                height: 700,
                freezesize: 0,
                 headerrowcount: 1
              });
    }

</script>
```

creas un estilo en tu archivo css o en la misma pagina

```
.GridviewScrollHeader TH, .GridviewScrollHeader TD 
{ 
    padding: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
   vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#03579D;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
} 
.GridviewScrollItem TD 
{ 
    padding: 3px; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
    border-bottom: 0.7px solid #AAAAAA;
    font-size:20px;

} 
.GridviewScrollPager  
{ 
    border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
} 
.GridviewScrollPager TD 
{ 
    padding-top: 3px; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    padding-right: 5px; 
} 
.GridviewScrollPager A 
{ 
    color: #666666; 
}.GridviewScrollPager SPAN
{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
background-color: #03579D;
  height: auto;
  margin-top:0;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.container2 {
background-color: #03579D;
 height: auto;
  margin-top:0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.GridviewScrollHeader2 TH, .GridviewScrollHeader TD 
{ 
    padding: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#03579D;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:14px;
} 
.GridviewScrollItem2 TD 
 { 
    padding: 3px; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
   border-bottom: 0.7px solid #AAAAAA;
    font-size:14px;

}
```

Y simplemente agregas el estilo a la tabla que quieres utilizar , y le colocas el id

```
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%"  align="center" cellspacing="0"     id="GridView11" style="border-collapse:collapse">
```

Para encabezado

```
<tr  class="GridviewScrollHeader">
```

Para el resto de las filas

```
<tr class="GridviewScrollItem"     bgcolor="#DBEAF5">
```